# extjs showing grey background without any css defined

Tags: css, extjs, gridpanel

I have extjs grid like this:

```
var grid = new FlexGridPanel({
   renderTo: 'someDiv',
   frame: false,
   columnLines: true,
   stripeRows: true,
   title: '<spring:message javaScriptEscape="true" code="someLabel"/>',
   height : 200,
   store: store,
   viewConfig: { forceFit:true},
   enableColumnHide: false,
   enableColumnMove: false,
   columns: [

       {header: '<spring:message javaScriptEscape="true" code="label.account.bank"/>',dataIndex:'bank' , width: 100, menuDisabled: true,sortable: true},
       {header: '<spring:message javaScriptEscape="true" code="label.account.number"/>',dataIndex:'accountNumber' , width: 100, menuDisabled: true,sortable: true},
       {header: '<spring:message javaScriptEscape="true" code="label.account.name"/>',dataIndex:'accountName', width: 200, menuDisabled: true,sortable: true},
       {header: '<spring:message javaScriptEscape="true" code="label.account.currency"/>',dataIndex:'currencyCode', width: 100, menuDisabled: true,sortable: true},
       {header: '<spring:message javaScriptEscape="true" code="label.account.type"/>',dataIndex:'accountTypeCode', width: 100, menuDisabled: true,sortable: true}
  ],
  sortInfo:{field: 'accountNumber', direction: "ASC"},
  sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect: true})
 });
```

Now, the column headers all have a nice grey background. But I did not specify any grey background or even any css class in the above definition. So how come there is a grey background?

Comment: You can use a developer console to help determine where CSS styles are coming from. Which browser are you using? I suggest FireBug for Firefox.

Comment: Thanks. Please post it as answer. This solves my problem  but I want to know where is the background color being set in the above code?

Comment: I'm not sure how that solved your problem.. but great! What do you find in FireBug? I don't see any CSS settings in your provided code. I assume it's being set somewhere else, probably in an included style sheet.

Comment: If your nice grey background looks similar to the nice grey background in [this page](http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-4.1.1a-gpl/examples/grid/array-grid.html) - it is the default extjs background, and it is defined in whatever css file you include for your ext library. This is assuming `FlexGridPanel` inherits from Ext's grid.